# How to log-in into android device and execute commands

Tags: android, linux, bash, shell, adb

I am writing a shell script in which I want to log-in into the Android device(adb shell) and execute some commands there. My script(script1.sh) looks like following:

```
# adb shell; cd sdcard; sh script2.sh &
```

but above command is not working. As soon as "adb shell" command is executed, I enter into Android shell after which the remaining two commands are not executed. If I type "exit" to come out from android shell, now remaining commands are executed in host shell:

```
./script1.sh: line 119: cd: /sdcard/: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are searching for `heredoc` (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Here_document#Unix_shells).

Example:

```
adb shell << ADB_SHELL
cd /sdcard
ls
exit
ADB_SHELL
```

**EDIT**: Before you execute things that possibly can harm your host, ensure the `adb shell` command worked properly and you are actually on the android device. Otherwise you would execute everything on your host machine.

Comment: If you want to redirect the output of `script2.sh` in a file, use shell piping: `sh sdcard2.sh > stdout.log`. What kind of output is that? Logs? Data that you want to process afterwards?

Comment: Thanks. Sorry my question has changed. It's working but my host script(script1.sh) is not exiting.

I am doing following in my host script(script1.sh)
adb shell << ADB_SHELL
cd /sdcard
sh script2.sh &
exit
ADB_SHELL

script2.sh runs a function in infinite loop on andriod device? How do I keep running script2.sh on android device but exit script1.sh on host?

Comment: It look it's not exiting adb remote shell. When I press Ctrl-C I come out from adb remote shell.Why "exit" command is not working in "heredoc"?

Comment: You could use `nohup` ([link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup)) to keep the process alive after you log out. **But**: This is bad style and i can't tell you if this works for you, since it depends on what the script is doing. If you need further assistance, you need to write a detailed explanation on what you are doing/planning to do.

Comment: If the script `script2.sh` doesn't terminate - the interpreter wont reach the next command. That's why your connection is still active.

Comment: I want to start a script from host(using adb) on android device which will keep logging cpu temperature once started. I want to start this script(on android device) from another script which I want to run on host machine.This script on host machine should start the script on android device and exit but script on android device should keep running. This is what I am trying to do.

Comment: with nohup also, not able to exit remote shell. 

This is what I have in my host script:


adb shell << ADB_SHELL
cd /sdcard
ls
nohup /system/bin/sh /sdcard/cpu_temp.sh -l &
echo "Exiting"
exit
ADB_SHELL

This is the output:

nohup /system/bin/sh /sdcard/cpu_temp.sh -l &
[1] 15908
root@arche:/sdcard # echo "Exiting"
Exiting
root@arche:/sdcard # exit (Still in the remote shell)

Comment: Please Post your scripts somewhere. I will have a look on it this evening.

Comment: Hi Thomas, I have put my scripts here:

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/go9iy7q8iitu1lz/AABJqhzsKB0yuWJR4Q-DrEYVa?dl=0

I call host script as ./host.sh -t

Comment: `nohup` wont 'return' because there are handles left on stout/stderr. Try executing your script `target.sh` (minimal example: http://pastebin.com/raw/hXaTmLhp) like this: `adb shell "cd /sdcard; nohup sh target.sh > nohup.log 2>&1 &"`. It rediects all output to the logfile `nohup.log`.

Comment: No Problem! If the initial post was the correct answer to your initial question, please mark it as answer :).

Comment: Just one question. This script shows on console every commands it's executing on android remote shell. Following is shown on console while commands are executing on android remote shell(root@arche:/#)

exit
root@arche:/ # cd /sdcard
root@arche:/sdcard # nohup sh target.sh -l > log_temp 2>&1 &
[1] 23066
root@arche:/sdcard # exit

How do I stop displaying commands getting executed on android remote shell?

Comment: You can hide the output of a command when you redirect it to `/dev/null` (e.g. `ls > /dev/null`). But i don't know how to supress the printing of the command itself.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use semicolon, example copy defalut.prop to /sdcard/

**~/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20140321/sdk/platform-tools/adb shell cp default.prop /sdcard/**

and to execute script in android you need to execute like this

**/system/bin/sh script.sh**